# Geometric-Variational idea of Sine

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I like to see sin(theta) as a property of a line making clockwise angle of theta with a horizontal axis.That property would dictate how much %  the vertical component of each point in the line represents in relation the hiponetuse component of the point. Sin(80degrees) = 0,98 . That is, choosing any point on a line making 80degrees with a horizontal axis, we get that the vertical component is only 98% of the hipotenusa component.

I'm trying to go from there to the graph of a sin function.

Can anyone help me see intuitively why this % ( the values of the sine ) goes smoothly decelerating ( forming that semi-circle in the sin graph ) as we increase the angle towards 90?       Why doesn't it go linearly decelerating for example ?

I don't wanna bring circles in since sin is just one component of the circle.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why isn't the graph of the sine function linear?

Well, think about a line of length 1 with one end at the origin, making an angle $\theta$ with the $x$-axis. As you say, $\sin\theta$ is the $y$-coordinate of the other end of this line.

Now think about what happens as this line rotates, and $\theta$ increases.

When $\theta$ is close to zero, changing $\theta$ by one degree will produce a significant change in the $y$ coordinate of the end of the line, so $\sin\theta$ will increase fairly rapidly.

Next, consider what happens when $\theta$ is around 85 degrees, say. In this case, increasing $\theta$ by one degree will make very little difference in the $y$ coordinate of the end of the line, so $\sin\theta$ will increase very slowly. By the time we get to $\theta = 90$ degrees, changing $\theta$ by a small amount won't change the $y$ coordinate at all, so we would expect the graph of the sine function to be flat (which indeed, it is).

Answer (score 1):

What you've identified is an important reason mathematicians don't use the classical geometric definition of sine (opposite-over-hypotenuse, SOH-CAH-TOA) as the formal definition - it's not clear what happens after 90 degrees since you can't have an obtuse right triangle, much less a triangle with more than 180 degrees!

You said you didn't want to bring circles in but let me show you a different way of looking at the unit circle that might be more enlightening: Consider a point on a unit circle centered at the origin. Draw the radius from the origin to that point - this will be your hypotenuse. Draw a segment from the point straight down to the x-axis - the length of this leg represents the sine of the angle $\theta$ between the radius and the x-axis. Draw another segment along the x-axis to where you dropped the perpendicular down already.

Now imagine moving from $\theta=0^o$ anticlockwise at a constant rate, say 1 degree per second, around the circle. You should see why the graph is the shape it is. Still confused? Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSine_curve_drawing_animation.gif) for what I mean.